# Power Query calculated columns versus new columns: Error: the syntax for ',' is incorrect

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm doing a simple change to a calculated column because of the plural issue, such as below:

[Calculated measure comes up as "1 reviews" in visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laTjN.png)

So I obviously don't want it to show up as "1 reviews". So I tried fixing the query for the measured column, and ran into an issue. Original query below and result:

```
Review Text = SUM(data[Total Reviews]) & " reviews"
```

[Result of measure: Success but plural only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp91e.png)

And what I want to do is make the "reviews" text plural if the SUM(data[Total Reviews]) >= 2, and keep it singular as "review" if it is not 2 or greater:

```
Review Text = IF(SUM(data[Total Reviews]) >= 2, data[Total Reviews]) & " reviews", data[Total Reviews]) & " review")
```

The problem is when I try to apply the if conditional above, the measure is unable to find the data[Total Reviews] for the true and false statements:

[Result of measure: Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V71bI.png)

Here's what the two relevant columns look like in the database:

[Total Reviews column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFl4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
Review Text = IF(SUM(data[Total Reviews]) >= 2, SUM(data[Total Reviews]) & " reviews", SUM(data[Total Reviews]) & " review")
```